# Dapp working in metamask but not in mist!

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, mist, dapp-development, dapps

I made a dapp using meteor. I deployed a smart contract in ropsten with remix. My dapp works fine working with metamask without running a geth node.Now if I open same application in Mist browser instead of chrome, no functionality works, and console gives following error- [image]

I started geth, with --ipc and opened connected my mist using geth only like said at this- http://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_mist.html

It gives same error?? Geth necessary or not? Any help appreciated please.
Keep in mind that I have to work so as to deploy it very soon. I have put my web3 address at 8545 even working without geth metamask works fine??curious about that.

Comment: Has your local node finished syncing? Ie, the latest block on your local node is greater than the block the contract was deployed on?

Comment: No, it's never stop syncing, it is importing new chain segment one at a time. Presently it is 1286835(the main network I think is above 4000000). Is it suppose to stop  at any point?
Also am I to expect some sumbit transaction window to pop up everytime to sign a transaction in my Dapp like it does in metamask??

Comment: Okay, it looks like your local node doesn't have the block with your contract on it - since it's about 2m blocks out. I think once you have your local node synced, it should work.

Comment: my contract was deployed at block number 1281316 and my current block is quite above that.

Comment: That block doesn't have any contract deployments on it: https://etherscan.io/txs?block=1281316

Comment: you're lookin in the main network i presume, I deployed in ropsten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to do web3.eth.defaultAccount=web3.eth.accounts[0]; before every invocation of any functionality in the Dapp, so that it picks the first wallet address provided by the mist. It picked the wallet address by itself with metamask.